# Use a special dns server for only a special website

Tags: linux, dns, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm wondering if it is possible, to use a certain DNS server only for some special sites.

I want to configure my Raspberry Pi as a DNS server. This server shall get the unknown adresses from the dns server of my internet provider by default. But for special websites it shall get the adresses from another dns server. Is this possible?

I installed Raspbian Wheezy and I'm flexible with the DNS server software.

I hope you understand my question.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to solve this is to let all the ordinary requests be proxied through the Raspberry Pi server as well.

Comment: So you mean, I should use the raspi as a proxy with the special DNS configured, when I want to see the special website and if not, I use no proxy? Did I understand this correctly? If yes, is there really no other way?

Comment: Your system can only have one DNS "system" (usually one have two servers for reliability). Your system cannot choose another DNS for certain sites. Since you don't want your Raspberrys DNS names be seen on the internet, your only choice is to let your computer ask the Raspberry, which asks the "real" servers. Another solution is to use a hosts-file, which is like a "local dns" but only on one computer.